# JAXB adding unwanted tags in XML and removing desired ones

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey, marshalling

I'm having the following structure of my classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "storage")
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "entries"
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {
    @XmlElement(name = "configuration")
    private Set<ClassB> entries;
    ...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "configuration")
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "name",
        "entries"
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B {
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "configurationEntry")
    private Set<ClassC> entries;
    ...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "configurationEntry")
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "property1",
        "property2",
        "property3"
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class C {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private String property3;
    ...
}
```

When I use Jersey to make me an XML out of that, I get the following output when I try to access the root container (Class A). I have no idea why instead of  tags are there  tags.

```
<Bes>
    <configuration>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <configurationEntry>
            <property1>...</property1>
            <property2>...</property2>
            <property3>...</property2>
        </configurationEntry>
        <configurationEntry>
            <property1>...</property1>
            <property2>...</property2>
            <property3>...</property2>
        </configurationEntry>
    </configuration>
    <configuration>
        <name>Name2</name>
        <configurationEntry>
            <property1>...</property1>
            <property2>...</property2>
            <property3>...</property2>
        </configurationEntry>
        <configurationEntry>
            <property1>...</property1>
            <property2>..</property2>
            <property3>...</property2>
        </configurationEntry>
    </configuration>
</Bes>
```

When I try to access one of ClassB containers, I get the following. (Similiar issue as previous), instead of  I get  and there is no  tag included.

```
<Aes>
    <configurationEntry>
        <property1>...</property1>
        <property2>...</property2>
        <property3>...</property2>
    </configurationEntry>
    <configurationEntry>
        <property1>...</property1>
        <property2>...</property2>
        <property3>...</property2>
    </configurationEntry>
<Aes>
```

The only one that works as expected is the one on the lowest level, Class C

```
<configurationEntry>
    <property1>...</property1>
    <property2>...</property2>
    <property3>...</property2>
</configurationEntry>
```

Just to be clear, my desired outputs are as following:

### When accessing storages (Class A) container:

```
<storage>
    <configuration>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <entries>
            <configurationEntry>
                <property1>...</property1>
                <property2>...</property2>
                <property3>...</property2>
            </configurationEntry>
            <configurationEntry>
                <property1>...</property1>
                <property2>...</property2>
                <property3>...</property2>
            </configurationEntry>
        </entries>
    </configuration>
    <configuration>
        <name>Name2</name>
        <entries>
            <configurationEntry>
                <property1>...</property1>
                <property2>...</property2>
                <property3>...</property2>
            </configurationEntry>
            <configurationEntry>
                <property1>...</property1>
                <property2>..</property2>
                <property3>...</property2>
            </configurationEntry>
        </entries>
    </configuration>
</storage>
```

### When accessing 2nd level container, Class B, I would like the following:

```
<configuration>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <entries>
        <configurationEntry>
            <property1>...</property1>
            <property2>...</property2>
            <property3>...</property2>
        </configurationEntry>
        <configurationEntry>
            <property1>...</property1>
            <property2>...</property2>
            <property3>...</property2>
        </configurationEntry>
    </entries>
</configuration>
```

### Class C is OK with:

```
<configurationEntry>
    <property1>...</property1>
    <property2>...</property2>
    <property3>...</property2>
</configurationEntry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I'm an idiot. -.-'

In my client code, for some reason I was retrieving `Set<B>` and `Set<C>` instead of `A` and `B`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

since i see tag `<Bes>` and `<Aes>` in class A and class B.. i feel that you have already defined root element.. i mean class A and Class B are subset of another class.. check this because an xml can have only one root element. if it is so then root element in class A and B is not valid. i don't see any issue with the xml defined in the class. for more information please visit http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-root-elements